# Проблемы с типизацией state в Redux Toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

Не могу сообразить какой тип указывать у стейта в редьюсере changeTodosName. Сейчас редьюсер changeTodosName подчёркивается тайпскриптом и выдаёт длинную ошибку -

> Type '(state: TodosType[], action: PayloadAction) => ({ id: string; } | { todosName: string | undefined; id: string; })[]' is not assignable to type 'CaseReducer<never[], { payload: any; type: string; }> | CaseReducerWithPrepare<never[], PayloadAction<any, string, any, any>>'.
> Type '(state: TodosType[], action: PayloadAction) => ({ id: string; } | { todosName: string | undefined; id: string; })[]' is not assignable to type 'CaseReducer<never[], { payload: any; type: string; }>'.
> Type '({ id: string; } | { todosName: string | undefined; id: string; })[]' is not assignable to type 'void | never[]'.
> Type '({ id: string; } | { todosName: string | undefined; id: string; })[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
> Type '{ id: string; } | { todosName: string | undefined; id: string; }' is not assignable to type 'never'.
> Type '{ id: string; }' is not assignable to type 'never'.

```js
import { createSlice, nanoid, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export interface TodosType {
    id: string
    todosName?: string
}

const todosSlice = createSlice({
    name: '@@todos',
    initialState: [],
    reducers: {
        addTodos: {
            reducer: (
                state: TodosType[],
                action: PayloadAction<TodosType>
            ) => {
                state.push(action.payload)
            },
            prepare: (todosName: string) => ({
                payload: {
                    id: nanoid(),
                    todosName,
                },
            }),
        },
        changeTodosName: (state: TodosType[], action: PayloadAction<TodosType>) => {
            return state.map((todo: { id: string }) =>
                todo.id === action.payload.id
                    ? {
                          ...todo,
                          todosName: action.payload.todosName,
                      }
                    : todo
            )
        },
    },
})

export const {
    addTodos,
    changeTodosName,
} = todosSlice.actions

export const todosReducer = todosSlice.reducer
```

Тип стейта в данном случае же это объекты внутри массива. Не пойму - какой тип указать, чтобы ts не ругался?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Type '({ id: string; } | { todosName: string | undefined; id: string; })[]' is not assignable to type
> 'void | never[]'.

Ожидается что `changeTodosName` вернет `void` или `never[]`.
То есть не нужно делать `return` в принципе. Находишь нужный элемент по id и обновляешь поле todosName.

```
  const todo = state.find(({ id }) => id === action.payload.id);
  if (todo) {
    todo.todosName = action.payload.todosName;
  }
```

Comment: Спасибо, понял!